# Boost thread, Eclipse + Cygwin, program silently exits immediately

Tags: c++, cygwin, eclipse-cdt, boost-thread

Tried to build and run a simple program with boost::thread. It builds fine, but silently (no console output at all) exits immediately when running, without even printing the welcome msg in main(). Really appreciate some hint.

```
...
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Linker
g++ -LE:/source/boost/boost_1_52_0/stage/lib -o "producerConsumer.exe"  ./src/SharedBuffer.o ./src/producerConsumer.o   -llibboost_thread -llibboost_system
Finished building target: producerConsumer.exe
```

By debug mode, I got this:

```
[New Thread 2312.0x214]
gdb: unknown target exception 0xc0000135 at 0x7c987406
```

0xc0000135 => STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND

Boost thread and system have been successfully built with Cygwin. In the lib dir specified in the g++ command (generated by Eclipse), there are:

```
libboost_thread.a
libboost_thread.dll.a
cygboost_thread.dll
```

So why STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND?? Suspect it's some configure issue. Really appreciate some hint.

WinXp SP3
Boost 1.52
gcc 4.5.3 for Cygwin 1.7.17(0.262/5/3)
Eclipse CDT 8.1.2

Comment: Make sure the boost dll is in the path?

Comment: Sometimes you'll need to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable additionally, that your program can find the DLL for loading.

Comment: run `ldd producerConsumer.exe`. it should list all the dlls needed by the program and their location.